# Oracle ERP: Auto Allocate of Serial number is not allowed in Organization

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, erp, inventory

I'm new to Oracle ERP and working with inventory module.
We've implemented a system integrated with ERP to do Move Orders working with PLSQL to update the seeded tables, which is working just fine except in some cases.
I'm getting the following error in my log :

**Auto Allocate of Serial number is not allowed in Organization: Manually allocate the Serial Number for Move Order: 620032.**

I would like to understand what is the meaning of **'Auto Allocate Serial Number'** and what are the steps to help sort it, knowing that this error is in PROD. I'd appreciate your prompt response ...

Comment: Show us your complete stored procedure